# ToolTwist Workbench error when running Ruby files

Tags: java, ruby, tooltwist

Using ToolTwist workbench, I am programatically executing ruby files using `java.lang.Runtime` to perform certain git command (e.g. loading of versions, synchronizing etc.)
but I'm getting the following error:

```
/Users/myaccount/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- xmlsimple (LoadError)
from /Users/myaccount/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /tooltwist/tooltwist_osx_7.0/devel/ttc_t/config/bin/checkLaunchpad.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

I am getting  same error before when I runned my ruby command in the terminal but able to resolve it just by running `gem install xml-simple` on the command line.

Do I need to call same command on my code?
Hope there's a better way of resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to restart you're ToolTwist Workbench.

1. Quit your ToolTwist Workbench.
2. Open a new terminal. New terminal will load up newly created env variable.
3. Start your eclipse.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already figured it out when I started my machine this morning. Thanks anyway.